# Tensorflow convolution vs. Tensorflow multiplication and sum vs. Numpy multiplication and sum

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am experiencing different results (on 16th least significant bit) while performing a single step of a dot product, implemented differently in TF and numpy.

The inputs are float32 5x5 image and 5x5 kernel.

```
i = tf.constant(I2D, dtype=tf.float32, name='i')    
k = tf.constant(K2D, dtype=tf.float32, name='k')
```

Scenario 1: Tensorflow convolution

```
tf_convolution = tf.nn.convolution(input=i4d, filter=k4d, padding="VALID")
```

Scenario 2: Tensorflow multiplication and sum

```
tf_multiply = tf.multiply(i, k)
tf_dot = tf.reduce_sum(tf_multiply)
```

Scenario 3: Numpy multiplication and sum

```
np_multiply = np.multiply(I2D, K2D)
np_dot = np.sum(np_multiply)
```

The results of element-wise multiplication in Scenario 2 and 3 are the same, but after the sum they are not.
Results remain the same regardless of whether it is executed using tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu.

I would like to better understand how it comes to this, what is the format type in which results are calculated (input is always float32, for numpy output is also float32), and whether there is a way to achieve that the results are bit identical.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:

Actual numbers:

```
I2D = np.array([[ 0.218994140625,  0.30615234375,   0.43115234375,     0.46923828125,   0.515869140625],
              [0.2880859375,    0.306640625 ,    0.361572265625,  0.430419921875,  0.408203125],
              [0.380615234375 , 0.318359375,     0.278076171875,  0.325927734375,   0.306640625],
              [0.319580078125,  0.30859375,      0.306640625,     0.28857421875,   0.29345703125],
              [0.28125,        0.319580078125 , 0.3515625 ,      0.3486328125,   0.3349609375]])


K2D = np.array([[0.0890502929687500,  0.0557556152343750, -0.0900573730468750,  0.0840759277343750,  0.1080932617187500],
            [0.0617370605468750, -0.0567016601562500,  0.0847473144531250,  0.0191040039062500, -0.0368041992187500],
            [0.1333923339843750, -0.0764160156250000,  0.1204223632812500, -0.1223754882812500, -0.0852966308593750],
            [0.1645507812500000, -0.0398864746093750, -0.0663452148437500,  0.0543823242187500,  0.1416015625000000],
            [-0.1589050292968750, -0.1628723144531250, -0.1723327636718750, -0.1340332031250000, 0.0513305664062500]
])
```

Results:

```
TF convolution = 0.001403801143169403076171875
TF multiplication + add = 0.00140382
numpy = 0.00140381604433
```

Comment: I get the same result in 2 and 3. Post an example when they are different

Comment: Used numbers and results are added.

Comment: Hm... I'm getting `0.00140382` for both. The next bit is in fact different. Are you computing TF on a CPU?

Comment: Now the results are without bias so the beginning part 0.0014038 is the same for all scenarios, but after that the differences come.

I tried both CPU and GPU, the results remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default `dtype` for these numpy arrays `I2D` and `K2D` is `np.float64`, so all operations are 64-bit. But you're comparing it to 32-bit operations result in tensorflow.

I've changed the `dtype=tf.float64` and got the same result up to the last digit:

```
i = tf.constant(I2D, dtype=tf.float64, name='i')
k = tf.constant(K2D, dtype=tf.float64, name='k')
```

... the result values:

```
0.00140381604433  # tensorflow
0.00140381604433  # numpy
```

Comment: Ok, great, also the same results for scenario 2 and 3 can be achieved if at the beginning  dtype='float32' is set for numpy arrays.
Now the biggest question remains - what happens inside TF convolution? TF convolution does not accept float64 input so I can switch everything to 32 but it is still different :(